# Concatenation by nth index in Gatling/Scala

Tags: scala, gatling

If I have a vector `myVector` of `Vector("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")`, I know I can set a session variable string of `"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9"` by doing:

```
.exec(session =>
        // Concatenate session variable
        session.set("myVectorConcat", session("myVector").as[Seq[String]].mkString(",")))
```

But I'd like to get a session variable that's a vector of strings, split by every 5 items (with the remaining items in the last index), such that `myVectorConcat` would be a vector of:

```
("1,2,3,4,5", "6,7,8,9")
```

I'm new to Gatling/Scala, so I'm wondering if this is possible in Gatling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted:

```
scala> Vector("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
  .grouped(5).map(_.mkString(",")).toVector

res0: Vector[String] = Vector(1,2,3,4,5, 6,7,8,9)
```

this is output from scala repl, but it actually looks like this

```
Vector("1,2,3,4,5", "6,7,8,9")
```

Comment: Thanks for the super clear answer, I'm starting to really love Scala.